# Error Running simpel RPC Program

Tags: c, rpc

I'm having trouble running the simplest RPC program. I want a program that will send a string from the client to a server and the server send the string back to the client. This is the echo.x:

```
program ECHO_PROG{
    version ECHO_VERS{
        string ECHO(string) = 1;
    } = 1;
} = 0x22233323;
```

After runnning rpcgen -a -C echo.x, I make the program and then I try to run

```
./echo_server &
./echo_client localhost
```

and I get the error :

```
call failed: RPC: Can't encode arguments.
```

Am I declaring the correct argument types in the .x file? Why am I getting that error? If I want to send a string to the server and have it echoed back am I approaching the problem correctly? I understand how to create an RPC that will return an int but returning a string is confounding me deeply. Please help if you're out there!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not happy returning a string... try this:

```
program ECHO_PROG{
    version ECHO_VERS{
        int ECHO(string) = 1;
    } = 1;
} = 0x22233323;
```

of course if the whole point is to return a string then you need to do some work -- I believe you have to wrap it in a custom type.

Comment: Can I return a struct?